# How to search in elasticsearch aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have articles saved in  elasticsearch and every article has field category where is array of numbers.

I have two servers, production and dev and on both servers is same php code which queries elastic, same versions of elastic,php,.... but on production I'm getting only N/A.

This is query:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/prodproduct/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "domains": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "category.keyword",
                "missing": "N/A",
                "size": 10,
                "order": {
                    "_count": "desc"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

So to repeat, this query gets categories on dev server but on production I get only N/A:

```
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 190,
    "successful" : 190,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2584032,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "domains" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "N/A",
          "doc_count" : 2584032
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I query specific article I see it has field category with number array.

What could be a problem?

I have spent several hours to try find solution but without any success.

Comment: I suspect a mapping issue. Can you compare the mapping of the `category` field in dev and production, are they the same?

Comment: yes, you are right. on dev server type is text and on production is long

Comment: There you go, if you fix that, it should work as expected. You'll need to recreate your production index and reindex your data.

Comment: thank you. can you post your answer and I will accept tonight when I do that and confirm theory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect a mapping issue, your `category` field probably has a different mapping in dev and in production.

If that's the case, you'll need to create a new index in production with the proper mapping and reindex your data in order for your query to work.